# Setting a parameter for returned string values

Tags: java, string, return

I am trying to create a game where a user enters a phrase, but the phrase can only be in lower case letters (if you catch my drift). So the program will prompt the user with a do-while loop. If the user enters anything like (1234567890, or !@#$%^&* or ASDFGH, the loop should re-prompt for the user to enter only lower case letters. I am extremely new to java, so my code is going to be really shitty. Here is is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program05 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Scanner scanner01 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputPhrase; 
    char inputChar;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a common phrase to begin!: ");
            inputPhrase = scanner01.nextLine(); 

        } while (!inputPhrase.equals(Character.digit(0,9)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) with the appropriate regex to test if it's all lowercase letters:

```
inputPhrase.matches("[a-z ]+") // consists only of characters a-z and spaces
```

So your loop would look like:

```
do {
    System.out.print("Enter a common phrase to begin!: ");
    inputPhrase = scanner01.nextLine(); 
} while (!inputPhrase.matches("[a-z ]+"));
```

Comment: Don't forget to add a space to the matches - the question specified a phrase

Comment: ..and commas, periods, quotes... :P depends on what OP wants in phrase. Covered by saying "with the appropriate regex"

Answer (score 0):

Try this i compiled this and it worked well

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 Scanner scanner01 = new Scanner(System.in);
 String inputPhrase = ""; 
 char inputChar;
    while(!inputPhrase.equals("exit")){
        System.out.print("Enter a common phrase to begin!: ");
        inputPhrase = scanner01.nextLine(); 
        for(int i = 0; i < inputPhrase.length(); i++){
            if(!Character.isLetter(inputPhrase.charAt(i))
            ||Character.isUpperCase(inputPhrase.charAt(i))){
                System.out.println("Input must be lowercase characters");
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```